# Добавить к файлу ресурсов по умолчанию префикс ru-RU

Tags: c#, .net, locale

Есть двуязычное webforms приложение (русский/английский)

Примеры файлов ресурсов:

- OrdersList.aspx.resx (для русского по умолчанию)
- OrdersList.aspx.en-US.resx

По требованиям необходимо именовать ресурсы по умолчанию так: 
FileName.aspx.ru-RU.resx (для этого случая OrdersList.aspx.ru-RU.resx)

Когда я переименовываю - валится эксепшн:
на методе HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(fileName, it.Trim()) (часть LINQ запроса)
an exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.
Make sure "OrdersList.aspx.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly

Что я сделал, чтобы переопределить формат файла для русского по умолчанию:

1. в свойствах проекта Application --> Assembly information установил нейтральный язык Russian (Russia)
   После этого в AssemblyInfo.cs появляется строка [assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en-US")]
   Переименовал OrdersList.aspx.resx -> OrdersList.aspx.ru-RU.resx
2. прописал перед входом на страницу в Page_Load Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new Culture|Info("ru-RU")
   Переименовал OrdersList.aspx.resx -> OrdersList.aspx.ru-RU.resx

Эксепшн в обоих случаях тот же. Кроме описанных способов решений не нашёл.
Что я сделал не так и что нужно сделать?